# List of Objects keeps overwriting itself

Tags: android, android-sqlite

The arraylist keeps overwriting itself even though I am initializing a new object in the loop each time.Inside the loop I am able to verify that the retrieved data is correct however when I print the list outside,it shows only the last object that has overwritten other elements in the list.

```
public ArrayList<CODTripsDetails> getCODTrips()
    { SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] projection = {
                KEY_COD_CUST_NAME,
                KEY_COD_DEL_FARE,
                KEY_COD_DEL_ADDR,
                KEY_COD_PICKDROP_DIST,
                KEY_COD_PICKUP_ADDR,
                KEY_COD_TIMESTAMP,
                KEY_COD_ORDER_ID
        };

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_COD_DETAILS,projection,
            null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    assert cursor != null;
    ArrayList<CODTripsDetails> array=new ArrayList<CODTripsDetails>();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        CODTripsDetails details=new CODTripsDetails();
        details.setName(cursor.getString(0));
        details.setdelFare(cursor.getString(1));
        details.setdelAddr(cursor.getString(2));
        details.setpickUpDropDist(cursor.getString(3));
        details.setpickUpAddr(cursor.getString(4));
        details.settimestamp(cursor.getString(5));
        details.setorderid(cursor.getString(6));
        Log.v("sql","sql=" +cursor.getString(3));
        array.add(details);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    Log.v("sql","sql1="+array.get(0).getpickUpAddr());
    Log.v("sql","sql1="+array.get(1).getpickUpAddr());

    return array;

}
```

Thanks in advance.

updated Code:

This is the entire mysqlitehelper class that I have written for retrieval and adding of data.

```
  public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        ArrayList<CODTripsDetails> array=new ArrayList<CODTripsDetails>();

        private static final String TABLE_EARNINGS = "Earnings";
        private static final String TABLE_RIDER = "Rider";
        private static final String TABLE_ORDER_DETAIL = "OrderDetail";
        private static final String TABLE_DELIVERY_DETAIL = "DeliveryDetail";
        private static final String TABLE_PICKUP_DETAIL = "PickUpDetail";
        private static final String TABLE_REJ_DETAILS="RejectedTripDetails";
        private static final String TABLE_COD_DETAILS="CODTripDetails";
        private static final String TABLE_COD_ORDER_DETAILS="CODOrderDetails";
        private static final String TABLE_ONLINE_DETAILS="OnlineTripDetails";
        private static final String TABLE_ONLINE_ORDER_DETAILS="OnlineOrderDetails";
        private static final String TABLE_PREV_EARNINGS = "PrevEarnings";
        private static final String TABLE_PREV_REJ_DETAILS="RejectedTripDetails";
        private static final String TABLE_PREV_COD_DETAILS="CODTripDetails";
        private static final String 

TABLE_PREV_COD_ORDER_DETAILS="CODOrderDetails";
    private static final String TABLE_PREV_ONLINE_DETAILS="OnlineTripDetails";
    private static final String TABLE_PREV_ONLINE_ORDER_DETAILS="OnlineOrderDetails";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Rider";

    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME="riderId";
    private static final String KEY_TOTAL_EARNING = "totalearnings";
    private static final String KEY_TOTAL_TRIPS = "totaltrips";
    private static final String KEY_RECEIVABLE_OR_PAYABLE = "payableorreceivable";
    private static final String KEY_COD_TRIPS = "codtrips";
    private static final String KEY_COD_FARE = "codfare";
    private static final String KEY_ONLINE_FARE = "onlinefare";
    private static final String KEY_ONLINE_TRIPS = "onlinetrips";
    private static final String KEY_KM_EXTRA="kmextra";
    private static final String KEY_DECLINED_FARE="declinedfare";
    private static final String KEY_DECLINED_TRIPS="declinedtrips";
    private static final String KEY_PICK_UP_EXTRA="pickupextraamt";
    private static final String KEY_INCENTIVE="incentive";
    private static final String KEY_COMMISSION="commission";
    private static final String KEY_SERVICE_TAX="servicetax";
    private static final String KEY_TOTAL_LOGIN_TIME="totalLoginTimeDetails";

    private static final String KEY_USER_ID="userid";
    private static final String KEY_USER_BLOCKED="blocked";
    private static final String KEY_USER_NAME="userName";
    private static final String KEY_USER_NUM="userNum";
    private static final String KEY_USER_IMAGE="userImage";


    private static final String KEY_ITEM_NAME="itemName";
    private static final String KEY_ITEM_QUANTITY="itemQty";
    private static final String KEY_ITEM_ORDER_ID="itemOrderId";


    private static final String KEY_DELIVERY_FARE="delFare";
    private static final String KEY_DELIVERY_ADDR="delAddr";
    private static final String KEY_DELIVERY_CODE="delCode";
    private static final String KEY_DELIVERY_LAT="delLat";
    private static final String KEY_DELIVERY_LNG="delLng";
    private static final String KEY_DELIVERY_TIME="delTime";
    private static final String KEY_DELIVERY_CONTACT_ADDR="delContactAddr";
    private static final String KEY_DELIVERY_NAME="delContactName";
    private static final String KEY_DELIVERY_NUM="delContactNum";

    private static final String KEY_CUST_NAME="custName";
    private static final String KEY_CUST_ID="custId";
    private static final String KEY_PICKUP_DIST="pickUpDis";
    private static final String KEY_PICKUP_DROP_DIST="pickUpDropDis";
    private static final String KEY_PICKUP_LAT="pickUpLat";
    private static final String KEY_PICKUP_LNG="pickUpLng";
    private static final String KEY_PICKUP_CONTACT_NUM="pickUpContactNum";
    private static final String KEY_PICKUP_CONTACT_NAME="pickUpContactName";
    private static final String KEY_PICKUP_ADDR="pickUpAddr";
    private static final String KEY_PAYMENT_MODE="paymentMode";
    private static final String KEY_ORDER_TIMESTAMP="timestamp";
    private static final String KEY_ORDER_ID="ordId";
    private static final String KEY_ORDER_TYPE="ordType";
    private static final String KEY_PICK_CONTACT_ADDR="pickContactAddr";


    private static final String KEY_REJ_CUST_NAME="rejCustName";
    private static final String KEY_REJ_TIMESTAMP="rejTimestamp";
    private static final String KEY_REJ_ORDER_ID="orderId";

    private static final String KEY_COD_CUST_NAME="custName";
    private static final String KEY_COD_DEL_FARE="delFare";
    private static final String KEY_COD_DEL_ADDR="delAddr";
    private static final String KEY_COD_PICKDROP_DIST="pickuDropDist";
    private static final String KEY_COD_PICKUP_ADDR="pickupAddr";
    private static final String KEY_COD_TIMESTAMP="timestamp";
    private static final String KEY_COD_ORDER_ID="orderId";

    private static final String KEY_ONLINE_CUST_NAME="custName";
    private static final String KEY_ONLINE_DEL_FARE="delFare";
    private static final String KEY_ONLINE_DEL_ADDR="delAddr";
    private static final String KEY_ONLINE_PICKDROP_DIST="pickuDropDist";
    private static final String KEY_ONLINE_PICKUP_ADDR="pickupAddr";
    private static final String KEY_ONLINE_TIMESTAMP="timestamp";
    private static final String KEY_ONLINE_ORDER_ID="orderId";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String CREATE_EARNINGS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_EARNINGS + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_TOTAL_EARNING + " TEXT," + KEY_TOTAL_TRIPS + " TEXT,"+ KEY_RECEIVABLE_OR_PAYABLE + " TEXT," + KEY_COD_TRIPS + " TEXT," + KEY_COD_FARE + " TEXT," + KEY_KM_EXTRA + " TEXT," + KEY_ONLINE_FARE + " TEXT," + KEY_ONLINE_TRIPS + " TEXT," + KEY_DECLINED_FARE + " TEXT," + KEY_DECLINED_TRIPS + " TEXT," + KEY_PICK_UP_EXTRA + " TEXT," + KEY_INCENTIVE + " TEXT," + KEY_COMMISSION + " TEXT," + KEY_SERVICE_TAX + " TEXT," + KEY_TOTAL_LOGIN_TIME + " TEXT" +" ) ";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_EARNINGS_TABLE);
        String CREATE_RIDERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_RIDER + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_USER_ID + " TEXT," + KEY_USER_BLOCKED + " TEXT," + KEY_USER_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_USER_NUM + " TEXT," + KEY_USER_IMAGE + " TEXT" + " ) ";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_RIDERS_TABLE);
        String CREATE_ORDER_DETAILS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_ORDER_DETAIL + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_ITEM_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_ITEM_QUANTITY + " TEXT" + " ) ";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ORDER_DETAILS_TABLE);
        String CREATE_DELIVERY_LOCATION_TABLE= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_DELIVERY_DETAIL + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_DELIVERY_FARE + " TEXT," + KEY_DELIVERY_ADDR + " TEXT,"+ KEY_DELIVERY_CODE + " TEXT," + KEY_DELIVERY_LAT + " TEXT," + KEY_DELIVERY_LNG + " TEXT," + KEY_DELIVERY_TIME + " TEXT," + KEY_DELIVERY_CONTACT_ADDR + " TEXT," + KEY_DELIVERY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_DELIVERY_NUM + " TEXT" + " ) ";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_DELIVERY_LOCATION_TABLE);
        String CREATE_PICKUP_LOCATION_TABLE= "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_PICKUP_DETAIL + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_CUST_NAME+ " TEXT," + KEY_CUST_ID + " TEXT," + KEY_ORDER_TIMESTAMP + " TEXT," + KEY_ORDER_ID + " TEXT," + KEY_ORDER_TYPE + " TEXT," + KEY_PAYMENT_MODE + " TEXT," + KEY_PICK_CONTACT_ADDR + " TEXT," + KEY_PICKUP_CONTACT_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_PICKUP_CONTACT_NUM + " TEXT," + KEY_PICKUP_ADDR + " TEXT," + KEY_PICKUP_DIST + " TEXT," + KEY_PICKUP_DROP_DIST + " TEXT," + KEY_PICKUP_LAT + " TEXT," + KEY_PICKUP_LNG + " TEXT" + " ) ";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_PICKUP_LOCATION_TABLE);
        String CREATE_REJ_DETAILS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_REJ_DETAILS + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_REJ_CUST_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_REJ_TIMESTAMP + " TEXT," + KEY_REJ_ORDER_ID + " TEXT" + " ) ";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_REJ_DETAILS_TABLE);
        String CREATE_COD_DETAILS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_COD_DETAILS + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_COD_CUST_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_COD_DEL_FARE + " TEXT," + KEY_COD_DEL_ADDR + " TEXT," +  KEY_COD_PICKDROP_DIST + " TEXT," + KEY_COD_PICKUP_ADDR + " TEXT," + KEY_COD_TIMESTAMP + " TEXT," + KEY_COD_ORDER_ID + " TEXT" + " ) ";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_COD_DETAILS_TABLE);
        String CREATE_ONLINE_DETAILS_PAGE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_ONLINE_DETAILS + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_ONLINE_CUST_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_ONLINE_DEL_FARE + " TEXT," + KEY_ONLINE_DEL_ADDR + " TEXT," +  KEY_ONLINE_PICKDROP_DIST + " TEXT," + KEY_ONLINE_PICKUP_ADDR + " TEXT," + KEY_ONLINE_TIMESTAMP + " TEXT," + KEY_ONLINE_ORDER_ID + " TEXT" + " ) ";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ONLINE_DETAILS_PAGE);
            String CREATE_ONLINE_ORDER_DETAILS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_ONLINE_ORDER_DETAILS + " ( "
                    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_ITEM_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_ITEM_QUANTITY + " TEXT," + KEY_ITEM_ORDER_ID + " TEXT" + " ) ";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ONLINE_ORDER_DETAILS_TABLE);
        String CREATE_COD_ORDER_DETAILS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_COD_ORDER_DETAILS + " ( "
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " + KEY_ITEM_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_ITEM_QUANTITY + " TEXT," + KEY_ITEM_ORDER_ID + " TEXT" + " ) ";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_COD_ORDER_DETAILS_TABLE);

        ///////////////////////////

        Log.v("table","tablescreated");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i2) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PICKUP_DETAIL);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_EARNINGS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DELIVERY_DETAIL);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_RIDER);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ORDER_DETAIL);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_REJ_DETAILS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_COD_DETAILS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_COD_ORDER_DETAILS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ONLINE_DETAILS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ONLINE_ORDER_DETAILS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PREV_EARNINGS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PREV_REJ_DETAILS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PREV_COD_DETAILS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PREV_COD_ORDER_DETAILS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PREV_ONLINE_DETAILS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PREV_ONLINE_ORDER_DETAILS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addDeliveryDetails(String delFare,String delAddr,String delCode,String delLat,String delLong,String delTime,String delContactAddr,String delName,String delNum)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues value=new ContentValues();
        value.put(KEY_DELIVERY_FARE,delFare);
        value.put(KEY_DELIVERY_ADDR,delAddr);
        value.put(KEY_DELIVERY_CODE,delCode);
        value.put(KEY_DELIVERY_LAT,delLat);
        value.put(KEY_DELIVERY_LNG,delLong);
        value.put(KEY_DELIVERY_TIME,delTime);
        value.put(KEY_DELIVERY_CONTACT_ADDR,delContactAddr);
        value.put(KEY_DELIVERY_NAME,delName);
        value.put(KEY_DELIVERY_NUM,delNum);
        db.insert(TABLE_DELIVERY_DETAIL, null, value);
        db.close();
    }

    public void addPickUpDetails(String custName,String custId,String time,String orderId,String orderType,String paymentMode,String pickcontactaddr,String pickcontactname,String pickcontactnum,String pickupaddr,String pickupdist,String pickupdropdist,String pickuplat,String pickuplng )
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues value=new ContentValues();
        value.put(KEY_CUST_NAME,custName);
        value.put(KEY_CUST_ID,custId);
        value.put(KEY_ORDER_TIMESTAMP,time);
        value.put(KEY_ORDER_ID,orderId);
        value.put(KEY_ORDER_TYPE,orderType);
        value.put(KEY_PAYMENT_MODE,paymentMode);
        value.put(KEY_PICK_CONTACT_ADDR,pickcontactaddr);
        value.put(KEY_PICKUP_CONTACT_NAME,pickcontactname);
        value.put(KEY_PICKUP_CONTACT_NUM,pickcontactnum);
        value.put(KEY_PICKUP_ADDR,pickupaddr);
        value.put(KEY_PICKUP_DIST,pickupdist);
        value.put(KEY_PICKUP_DROP_DIST,pickupdropdist);
        value.put(KEY_PICKUP_LAT,pickuplat);
        value.put(KEY_PICKUP_LNG,pickuplng);
        db.insert(TABLE_PICKUP_DETAIL, null, value);
        db.close();
    }


    public String getCustId()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] projection = {
                KEY_CUST_ID
        };
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_PICKUP_DETAIL,projection,
                null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        assert cursor != null;
        String custId=cursor.getString(0);
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return custId;
    }



    public String getPickUpDist()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] projection = {
                KEY_PICKUP_DIST
        };
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_PICKUP_DETAIL,projection,
                null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        assert cursor != null;
        String pickupdist=cursor.getString(0);
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return pickupdist;
    }

    public String getPickUpDropDist()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] projection = {
                KEY_PICKUP_DROP_DIST
        };
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_PICKUP_DETAIL,projection,
                null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        assert cursor != null;
        String pickupdropdist=cursor.getString(0);
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return pickupdropdist;
    }

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }







    public void addCODOrders(String name,String delFare,String delAddr,String pickupdropDist,String pickupAddr,String timestamp,String orderid)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_COD_CUST_NAME,name);
        values.put(KEY_COD_DEL_FARE,delFare);
        values.put(KEY_COD_DEL_ADDR,delAddr);
        values.put(KEY_COD_PICKDROP_DIST,pickupdropDist);
        values.put(KEY_COD_PICKUP_ADDR,pickupAddr);
        values.put(KEY_COD_TIMESTAMP,timestamp);
        values.put(KEY_COD_ORDER_ID,orderid);
        db.insert(TABLE_COD_DETAILS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public void addOnlineOrders(String name,String delFare,String delAddr,String pickupAddr,String pickupdropDist,String timestamp,String orderid)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ONLINE_CUST_NAME,name);
        values.put(KEY_ONLINE_DEL_FARE,delFare);
        values.put(KEY_ONLINE_DEL_ADDR,delAddr);
        values.put(KEY_ONLINE_PICKDROP_DIST,pickupdropDist);
        values.put(KEY_ONLINE_PICKUP_ADDR,pickupAddr);
        values.put(KEY_ONLINE_TIMESTAMP,timestamp);
        values.put(KEY_ONLINE_ORDER_ID,orderid);
        db.insert(TABLE_ONLINE_DETAILS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }


    public ArrayList<CODTripsDetails> getCODTrips()
    { SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] projection = {
                KEY_COD_CUST_NAME,
                KEY_COD_DEL_FARE,
                KEY_COD_DEL_ADDR,
                KEY_COD_PICKDROP_DIST,
                KEY_COD_PICKUP_ADDR,
                KEY_COD_TIMESTAMP,
                KEY_COD_ORDER_ID
        };

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_COD_DETAILS,projection,
                null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        assert cursor != null;

        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            CODTripsDetails details=new CODTripsDetails();
            details.setName(cursor.getString(0));
            details.setdelFare(cursor.getString(1));
            details.setdelAddr(cursor.getString(2));
            details.setpickUpDropDist(cursor.getString(3));
            details.setpickUpAddr(cursor.getString(4));
            details.settimestamp(cursor.getString(5));
            details.setorderid(cursor.getString(6));
            Log.v("sql","sql=" +cursor.getString(3));
            array.add(details);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        Log.v("sql","sql1="+array.get(0).getpickUpAddr());
        Log.v("sql","sql1="+array.get(1).getpickUpAddr());

        return array;

    }












    public CODTripsDetails[] getOnlineTrips()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] projection = {
                KEY_ONLINE_CUST_NAME,
                KEY_ONLINE_DEL_FARE,
                KEY_ONLINE_DEL_ADDR,
                KEY_ONLINE_PICKDROP_DIST,
                KEY_ONLINE_PICKUP_ADDR,
                KEY_ONLINE_TIMESTAMP,
                KEY_ONLINE_ORDER_ID
        };
        int i=0;
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_ONLINE_DETAILS,projection,
                null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        assert cursor != null;
        CODTripsDetails[] array=new CODTripsDetails[cursor.getCount()];
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            array[i]=new CODTripsDetails(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),cursor.getString(6));
            i++;
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return array;
    }

    public void addCODORderDetails(String itemName,String itemQuantity,String orderid)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ITEM_NAME,itemName);
        values.put(KEY_ITEM_QUANTITY,itemQuantity);
        values.put(KEY_ITEM_ORDER_ID,orderid);
        db.insert(TABLE_COD_ORDER_DETAILS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public void addOnlineORderDetails(String itemName,String itemQuantity,String orderid)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_ITEM_NAME,itemName);
        values.put(KEY_ITEM_QUANTITY,itemQuantity);
        values.put(KEY_ITEM_ORDER_ID,orderid);
        db.insert(TABLE_ONLINE_ORDER_DETAILS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }

    public OrderDetail[] getCODRderDetails(String orderid) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] projection = {
                KEY_ITEM_NAME,
                KEY_ITEM_QUANTITY
        };
        int i = 0;
        String where="itemOrderId=?";
        String[] args={orderid};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_COD_ORDER_DETAILS, projection,
                where, args, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        assert cursor != null;
        OrderDetail[] array = new OrderDetail[cursor.getCount()];
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            array[i] = new OrderDetail(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1));
            i++;
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return array;
    }


    public OrderDetail[] getOnlineOrderDetails(String orderid) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String[] projection = {
                KEY_ITEM_NAME,
                KEY_ITEM_QUANTITY
        };
        int i = 0;
        String where="itemOrderId=?";
        String[] args={orderid};
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_ONLINE_ORDER_DETAILS, projection,
                where, args, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        assert cursor != null;
        OrderDetail[] array = new OrderDetail[cursor.getCount()];
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            array[i] = new OrderDetail(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1));
            i++;
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return array;
    }



}
```

Comment: I am just retrieving this data in an Activity file and sending it to an adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Move `ArrayList<CODTripsDetails> array=new ArrayList<CODTripsDetails>();` outside the function. In your case, the scope of `ArrayList<CODTripsDetails> array` is in the function only and as soon as the function terminates, **array** is deleted.

**EDIT**

```
public class SomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MySQLiteHelper db;
    private ArrayList<CODTripsDetails> array=new ArrayList<CODTripsDetails>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);

        array = db.getCODTrips(); // This sets your array to data
    }
}
```

Comment: That didnt help.It's still being overwritten.

Comment: This issue is not related to database. You should declare your ArrayList globally i.e in the class not in function

Comment: I did do that.I declared the arraylist outside the function.You can see that in the updated code.

Comment: ah I see. Do not declare ArrayList in MySQLiteHelper. Declare it in the activity class from which you are accessing database

Comment: then how do I return the retrieved data from the mysqlitehelper class to the activity?

Comment: See my updated answer. Access the database like this in your activity

Comment: I understand that but could you show me how I would return the data from the function in the sqlitehelper class i.e. how do I retrieve the data and store it in an array/arraylist and then return it.

Comment: You are already doing it. See the return type of your function. Its actually populating array and returning it.

Comment: Yeah but the array that I am returning consists of overwritten values.That is the main issue that I am trying to rectify.